# Can't highlight a row in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I am trying to highlight a specific row in a DataGridView.

But the following code is not working:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["Job No"].Value.ToString().Equals("Sub Total"))
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;                    
    }   
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: i am using C# to for this code

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows) 
{ 
    if (row.Cells["Job No"].Value.ToString().Equals("Sub Total")) 
    { 
        DataGridView1.rows[row.index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    } 
}
```